Why I am I experiencing VMware input bugs on Linux Mint? Not able to grab output of input
I have been using Windows for years now. I've recently multi-booted Linux on my laptop. I installed VMware and decided to create two VMs.
My issue was that whenever I turn on a VM, VMware grabs my input. After that, I have tried changing the keyboard shortcut from Shift+Ctrl+Alt+Win to Ctrl+Alt+Win and again to Ctrl+Win and none of them worked.
Another thing, is that whenever I boot into Windows 10 PE (I used Windows 10 1511's PE) Shift+F10 doesn't run command prompt. Shift, Alt don't work inside the VM. Even though, I have locked my input, Alt+Tab is on my host.
This problem is driving me nuts to the point I'm thinking of using Windows 10 LTSC 2019.
Now, I got some new issues:

"Could not open /dev/vmmon: No such file or directory.
Please make sure that the kernel module `vmmon' is loaded. OK."


Another error message after the other one:

"Failed to initialize monitor device. OK."


Another error after the last one:

"Unable to change virtual machine power state: Transport (VMDB) error -14: Pipe connection has been broken. OK."


I can't start up my vm at all. Yesterday, I could. I had this error before. (VMware vmmon & vmnet 17.5.1 and Linux kernel 6.8.0 won't compile) I tried Daniil's response and usually it works. I tried his command 2 times today to get these 3 errors.
My kernel version is 6.8.0-49-generic BTW.
Here are my specs:

Operating System: Linux Mint 22 Cinnamon Cinnamon Version 6.2.9
Linux Kernel: 6.8.0-49-generic
Processor: Intel Core™ i5-1035G1 CPU @ 1.00GHz x 4 Memory 19.3 GIB
Hard Drives: 1240.3 GB
Graphics Card: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake)
Display Server: Wayland

Here are my detailed specs:
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-49-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0 clocksource: tsc
  Desktop: Cinnamon v: 6.2.9 tk: GTK v: 3.24.41 wm: Muffin v: 6.2.0 vt: 8 dm: LightDM v: 1.30.0
    Distro: Linux Mint 22 Wilma base: Ubuntu 24.04 noble
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 82C5 v: Lenovo V15-IIL serial: <superuser required> Chassis:
    type: 10 v: Lenovo V15-IIL serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: LNVNB161216 v: NO DPK serial: <superuser required>
    part-nu: LENOVO_MT_82C5_BU_idea_FM_V15-IIL uuid: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: DKCN53WW
    date: 05/31/2021
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 8.4 Wh (34.4%) condition: 24.4/30.6 Wh (79.6%) power: 9.0 W volts: 7.0
    min: 7.6 model: CPT-COS L16C2PB2 type: Li-poly serial: <filter> status: discharging cycles: 2084
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Core i5-1035G1 bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled arch: Ice Lake
    rev: 5 cache: L1: 320 KiB L2: 2 MiB L3: 6 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1231 high: 1301 min/max: 400/3600 cores: 1: 1300 2: 1208 3: 1300 4: 1099
    5: 1301 6: 1300 7: 1062 8: 1282 bogomips: 19046
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Iris Plus Graphics G1 vendor: Lenovo driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-11 ports:
    active: eDP-1 empty: HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:8a56 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Syntek Integrated Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1
    bus-ID: 1-5:3 chip-ID: 174f:1176 class-ID: 0e02
  Display: wayland server: X.org v: 1.21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915 display-ID: 0
  Monitor-1: eDP-1 model: ChiMei InnoLux 0x15e6 res: 1366x768 dpi: 101
    size: 344x193mm (13.54x7.6") diag: 394mm (15.5") modes: 1366x768
  API: EGL v: 1.5 hw: drv: intel iris platforms: device: 0 drv: iris device: 1 drv: swrast
    surfaceless: drv: iris wayland: drv: iris x11: drv: iris inactive: gbm
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2 glx-v: 1.4
    direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (ICL GT1) device-ID: 8086:8a56
    display-ID: :0.0
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:34c8 class-ID: 0403
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-49-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse status: active
    2: wireplumber status: active
  Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: off (using pipewire-pulse)
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Lenovo
    driver: rtw_8822ce v: N/A pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: 3000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
    chip-ID: 10ec:c82f class-ID: 0280
  IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Realtek Bluetooth Radio driver: btusb v: 0.8 type: USB rev: 1.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1
    bus-ID: 1-10:4 chip-ID: 0bda:c02f class-ID: e001 serial: <filter>
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 5.1 lmp-v: 10
    sub-v: d2e3 hci-v: 10 rev: cc6 class-ID: 7c010c
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.13 TiB used: 41.67 GiB (3.6%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST1000LM049-2GH172 size: 931.51 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s
    tech: HDD rpm: 7200 serial: <filter> fw-rev: LXM4 scheme: MBR
  ID-2: /dev/sdb vendor: Seagate model: WDC WDS240G2G0B-00EPW0 size: 223.57 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s
    tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: 0400 scheme: GPT
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 55.62 GiB used: 41.64 GiB (74.9%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sdb7
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 95 MiB used: 32.9 MiB (34.6%) fs: vfat dev: /dev/sdb2
Swap:
  ID-1: swap-1 type: partition size: 3.81 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) priority: -2 dev: /dev/sdb8
USB:
  Hub-1: 1-0:1 info: hi-speed hub with single TT ports: 12 rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1
    chip-ID: 1d6b:0002 class-ID: 0900
  Device-1: 1-1:2 info: HP Elite Keyboard type: keyboard,HID driver: hid-generic,usbhid
    interfaces: 2 rev: 1.1 speed: 1.5 Mb/s lanes: 1 power: 100mA chip-ID: 03f0:034a class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: 1-5:3 info: Syntek Integrated Camera type: video driver: uvcvideo interfaces: 2
    rev: 2.0 speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 power: 500mA chip-ID: 174f:1176 class-ID: 0e02
  Device-3: 1-10:4 info: Realtek Bluetooth Radio type: bluetooth driver: btusb interfaces: 2
    rev: 1.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 power: 500mA chip-ID: 0bda:c02f class-ID: e001 serial: <filter>
  Hub-2: 2-0:1 info: super-speed hub ports: 6 rev: 3.1 speed: 10 Gb/s lanes: 1 chip-ID: 1d6b:0003
    class-ID: 0900
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 50.0 C mobo: N/A
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A
Repos:
  Packages: 2359 pm: dpkg pkgs: 2339 pm: flatpak pkgs: 20
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/brave-browser-archive-keyring.gpg] https: //brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/chrome-remote-desktop.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] http: //dl.google.com/linux/chrome-remote-desktop/deb/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-noble.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/danielrichter2007-grub-customizer-noble.gpg] https: //ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu noble main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/filips_FirefoxPWA_any.list
    1: deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/filips_FirefoxPWA-archive-keyring.gpg] https: //packagecloud.io/filips/FirefoxPWA/any/ any main
    2: deb-src [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/filips_FirefoxPWA-archive-keyring.gpg] https: //packagecloud.io/filips/FirefoxPWA/any/ any main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/freedownloadmanager.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/freedownloadmanager.gpg] https: //debrepo.freedownloadmanager.org/ jammy main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https: //dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/librewolf.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/librewolf.gpg] https: //deb.librewolf.net bookworm main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb https: //mirror.freedif.org/LinuxMint/packages wilma main upstream import backport
    2: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http: //archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http: //security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security main restricted universe multiverse
Info:
  Memory: total: 20 GiB note: est. available: 19.33 GiB used: 3.85 GiB (19.9%)
  Processes: 299 Power: uptime: 25m states: freeze,mem,disk suspend: deep wakeups: 0
    hibernate: platform Init: systemd v: 255 target: graphical (5) default: graphical
  Compilers: gcc: 13.2.0 Client: Cinnamon v: 6.2.9 inxi: 3.3.34


Thanks Giacomo1968 for editing my post! I appreciate your edits.
